# Priority Queue (sink operations)

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am practising on priority queue topic from Algorithms book by robert sedgwick. 
In a question we have to implement `sink()` method with out `j < N` condition.

```
private void sink(int k){
    while (2*k <= N){
         int j = 2*k;
         if (j < N && less(j, j+1)) j++;
         if (!less(k, j)) break;
         exch(k, j);
         k = j;
    }
}

private boolean less(int i, int j){ 
    return pq[i].compareTo(pq[j]) < 0;
}

private void exch(int i, int j){ 
    Key t = pq[i]; 
    pq[i] = pq[j]; 
    pq[j] = t;
}
```

Above is code from book by Robert sedgwick check page no. 329 and question no 2.4.13

Comment: `if (j<N && less(j, j+1)) j++` If you remove the condition `j<N` then it would become `if (less(j-1, j)) j--;` Think about it! So, according to this, you will also need to change the while conditional: `while (2*k+1 <= N)` and assign `int j=2*k+1;` The rest is pretty much the same. Now that we have changed the while conditional, we need to handle one edge case where `k` has only one child. So do this outside the loop: `if (2*i == N && less(k, N)) {.. exch..} ... and then restore the previous k to pq[k]`

Comment: So what's your question?